# AWS User Data fails with invalid region name when it is correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, scp, policy, tagging

user data bash script fails with Provided region_name doesn't match a support format.

when running the script from comand line works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
Hostname=”`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/hostname`”
InstanceId=”`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id`”
Region=”`wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/region`”
echo $Region
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $InstanceId --tags Key=Hostname,Value=$Hostname --region $Region
```

Comment: 1. You're missing the `$` before hostname in `Key=Hostname` 2. what is the `$Region` that fails? what is echoed to console?

Comment: Be careful -- your quote characters are non-standard, as if the text has been copied from Microsoft Word rather than a pure text editor. I fixed them and it worked fine for me. If you ever need to debug a User Data script, look in the log file: `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue aws was changing the double quote to left and right double quote. I recoded it.

```
#! /bin/bash
Hostname=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/hostname)
InstanceId=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
Region=$(wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/placement/region)
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $InstanceId --tags Key=Hostname,Value=$Hostname --
region $Region
```

Comment: I think your text editor and your quotes are the issues, not from aws.